# Getting access to gbdxtools

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use the gbdxtools package in python for downloading satellite images automatically. Unfortunately I'm struggling with always getting my s3 information with `gbdx.s3.info`. Does anybody have an idea to share?

```
>>> from gbdxtools import Interface
>>> gbdx = Interface()
Please create a GBDX credential file at ~/.gbdx-config with these contents:
[gbdx]
auth_url = https://geobigdata.io/auth/v1/oauth/token/
client_id = your_client_id
client_secret = your_client_secret
user_name = your_user_name
user_password = your_password
>>> gbdx = Interface()
>>> gbdx.s3.info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/gbdx_env35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gbdxtools/s3.py", line 44, in info
    self._info = self._load_info()
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/gbdx_env35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gbdxtools/s3.py", line 63, in _load_info
    r = self.gbdx_connection.get(url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Do you have your credentials configured correctly?  It looks like you don't based on the error message.  You can also open an issue in the [GBDX tools](https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/gbdxtools) GitHub.

Comment: Anyone else reading this question please note that the contents of the .gbdx-config file have changed.

This is all you need now
https://github.com/tdg-platform/gbdx-auth#ini-file